# java - Android HttpPost Black Screen while sending files to server

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I am sending images and audio files to my php server. I am using Asynctask for this. I have two activities in my program. The problem is if I launch my second activity (AudioActivity) from MainActivity like this

```
upload_audio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

});
```

then when i click the button `upload_audio` the screen goes black but the process still running successfully . so if i make this audio activity my mainActivity then everything works perfect.so how can i make my app still visible during processing files while launching activity from MainActivity.hope you understand my question

here is my code of AudioActivity

```
public class AudioActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 2;
    String selectedPath = "";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        upload();
    }


    public void upload() {
        ArrayList<Uri> fileName = getFileList(this);
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < fileName.size() ; i++ )
        {
            try {
                selectedPath = getPath(fileName.get(i)).toString();
                System.out.println(getPath(fileName.get(i)));

                new AudioSync(selectedPath).execute(getPath(fileName.get(i))).get();
                // AudioSync sync = new AudioSync(getPath(fileName.get(i))).get;
                //new AudioSync().execute("").get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }


    private ArrayList<Uri> getFileList(Context context) {
        Cursor actualimagecursor = null;
        ArrayList<Uri> fileList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        try
        {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID };
            actualimagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
                    null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

            int actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

            for ( int i = 0 ; i < actualimagecursor.getCount() ; i++ )
            {
                actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                String fileName = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
                fileList.add(( Uri.withAppendedPath( MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, fileName )));
            }
            return fileList;
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your AudioActivity here

Comment: display progress dialog when uploading in progress and also u need to set some layout to your AudioActivity

Comment: @MD NO i dont want to show a uploading progress. i am showing a checkbox .and when user check the checkbox the backup of his audiofiles will start

Comment: then why u need to go to another activity? put your all logic into main activity becoz indirectly your uploading files into background thread.

Comment: @MD ok thankyou. now i definitely do this.

Comment: @hellosheikh Your app will hang if you use the UI thread (main thread in the Activity) to upload or play music or ...

Comment: @K.C. yeah thanks for letting me know .the app is giving me problems .. sometimes when i am uploading it gives me force close message. what should i do then ?

Comment: @hellosheikh Like I said in my answer below. Use a Service to do your background thingy (uploading, playing music, ...)

Comment: i have no experience in using service in android. is there any tutorial you can provide

Comment: @hellosheikh I've improved code formatting in this question, but next time please do it before posting your question.  I mean consistent indentation, reasonable usage of blank lines etc.  It's easier to get an answer when the question is easy to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to create an Activity for uploading or playing Audio. Activities are always linked with views and are use to interact with the user.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

You want to use a service to do that: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html